# How to fix "Permission Denied" in Git Bash in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, git, pip, git-bash

Whenever I tried to run this command: `python get-pip.py`, git bash gave me this response: `bash: /c/Users/Sergio Ley/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied`. I don't know how to fix this and have tried to search this up with no avail. Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the command **PY** instead of Python [# Invoking The Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#invoking-the-interpreter) (python.org)

Answer (score 0):

I got fed up with all the permission issues of Microsoft Store's Python app, so I just uninstalled it and downloaded Python straight from python.org. After that, everything was smooth sailing in Git Bash.

Answer (score -1):

### **For Windows**

Instead of using -

> <strike>`python3 manage.py runserver`</strike>

Use - **(It works!!!)**

> `py manage.py runserver`